# Javascript - How do i remove a covering/wrapper object from an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Currently coded in a variable, I have an array of objects (see A where I address the id of the first battery cell in my array).

When getting the data through json, the same array of objects is covered/wrapped though an (unwelcome) object. See attached screenshot.

A: jsonv[0].id

B: jsont.battdat[0].id

What I would like to have is:

Solution(C): jsont.battdat[0].id -> jsont[0].id

To get this the surrounding object jsont has to be removed and the array battdat has to be renamed to jsont

Finally then i can access the id of the first cell through jsont[0].id.

As additional explanation see the attached screenshot: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple with reassignment:

```
jsont = jsont.battdat;
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. (And I didn't make a complicated statement).

Comment: No worries @klausz, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer.